# hide table row if all tds are empty

Tags: jquery

Is there an easy way to do this without a each loop.

I want to hide the entire `<tr>` but only if a all its `<td>`s are blank.
The table is dynamically generated so the blank rows could be any where.

```
$('#table1 tr:has(td):empty').remove();
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="table1">
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
</tr>
<tr >
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
...
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why does it have to be done without an each loop?

Comment: How would you do it with an each?

Comment: So there was no actual reason for the no-`each()` restriction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to use each, you can do it like:

```
$('#table1 tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td:empty').length) $(this).remove();
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/agz7z/)**

Comment: Which method is better? The each looks easier to understand?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a better option here. You could run a performance comparison test on jsperf.com to see if one is faster, but there's more than one way to skin a cat with jQuery so take your pick.

Comment: @Hello-World: it's worth noting that j08691 and myself took slightly different approaches to your problem; my solution hides a table row only if *all* the `td` elements contained within are empty, whereas this solution hides the `tr` [if *any* of the `td` elements are empty](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/agz7z/1/). So which is 'best' depends on your use case, and which you find easiest to understand and apply.

Comment: David Thomas is correct. You can modify the if statement to be `if ($(this).find('td:empty').length==$(this).find('td').length) $(this).remove();` if you just want to check that all cells in a row are empty.

Answer (score 12):

I'd suggest, although this still, implicitly, examines each of the `tr` elements:

```
$('tr').filter(
    function(){
        return $(this).find('td').length == $(this).find('td:empty').length;
    }).hide();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TjfPa/).

This is, with quite some cross-browser difficulties, *sort of* possible in CSS, using the `:not()` and `:empty` pseudo-selectors:

```
tr td:empty {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
}

​td:not(:empty) ~ td:empty {
    visibility: visible;
    height: 100%;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TjfPa/1/).

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`:empty` (jQuery) selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- CSS:

  - [`:empty`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#empty-pseudo).
  - [General sibling `~` combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).
  - [`:not()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation).

Comment: +1 I think this is more readable and maybe even more effective than a piled up selector full of jQuery custom selectors.

Comment: I like the css, but it makes the cells hidden if the first one is empty, but the second one not empty. I prefer if it only hid the cells if all are empty.