# Rows not being remove or hidden with jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery. I tried the below 2 scripts but they didn't work. I verified that `att1_preview_lbl.Text` is empty and same for `att1_preview`, but the row did not hide or got removed. Can someone please help?

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $('.EventDetail tr').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('td').filter(function() {
            return !$.trim($(this).text());
        }).length;
    }).hide();
</script>
<script>
    $("table tr").each(function() {
        var cell = $.trim($(this).find('td').text());
        if (cell.length == 0) {
            console.log('empty');
            $(this).addClass('nodisplay');
        }
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0" style="border-style: groove">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="PaddedRight" style="border-style: groove">
                <asp:Label ID="att1_preview_lbl" runat="server">Attribute 1</asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="border-style: groove">
                <asp:Label ID="att1_preview" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="PaddedRight" style="border-style: groove">
                <asp:Label ID="att2_preview_lbl" runat="server">Attribute 2</asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="border-style: groove">
                <asp:Label ID="att2_preview" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="PaddedRight" style="border-style: groove">
                <asp:Label ID="att3_preview_lbl" runat="server">Attribute 3</asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="border-style: groove">
                <asp:Label ID="att3_preview" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have below on the top of my code 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">include("jquery-1.3.2.min.js");</script>

Comment: that's not the proper way to create a script tag. Not to mention that version is about 7-8 years old. Try replacing with `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: updated to <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> but still didn't work.. you mentioned something about script tag ?

Comment: Sooo, you want the row hidden if the 2nd cell in the row is empty?

Comment: if first or second is empty ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK--I got it after a couple of false starts.  Iterate through the cells of each row, and set `hasData` to true if any of the cells in that row have data.  When the cell iteration is complete, hide the row if `hasData` is still false.

```
//loop through the rows
$("table tr").each(function (i, row) {
    //reset hasData to false for each row
    var hasData = false;

    //loop through the cells of each row
    $(row).children().each(function (i, cell) {
        //If a cell has data, set hasData to true
        if ($(cell).text().trim().length != 0) {
            hasData = true;
        }
    });

    //Hide the row if hasData is still false after iterating through the cells
    if (hasData == false) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: A couple more answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346271/hide-table-row-if-all-tds-are-empty but I couldn't get the first one to work--didn't try the second.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there *may be* a problem with your second script tag. Your original function iterates the `tr` elements and attempts to set the `class="nodisplay"` on the `row` element based off the first cell's value only... did you mean to set this class on the individual `cell` like this?

EDIT: I added the [jQuery Empty Selector](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

```
<script>
    $("table tr").each(function () {
        var cells = $(this).find('td:empty');
        if (cells.length > 0) {
            console.log('empty');
            $(this).addClass('nodisplay');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: didn't make a difference,, tbody have anything to do with this?

Comment: This sets the class='nodisplay' when any cell is empty, perhaps I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: i want the jquery function the remove the row when one or both <td> are empty.. that's all

Comment: Updated, I used the jQuery `:empty` selector to detect for `td` elements that are empty.

Comment: still not working.. i added this script below </table> and updated 
            <td class="PaddedRight" style="border-style: groove">
                <asp:Label ID="att1_preview_lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>   to make sure the row is always empty but i am still getting an empty row on the screen and it is now hiding..

Comment: i tried this but still no luck, i even added an alert message at the end of this script just to make sure it is running and it is but i am still getting and empty row in my table..

Comment: i tried this function $('#myTableRow').remove(); and named one of them id="myTableRow" but it didn't change anything.. am i missing something here? again thanks for your help !

Comment: I tested this code on my machine, it sets the class properly. It seem you must have a problem you your CSS class `nodisplay`.