# How to hide DataTable wrapper when there's no data available?

Tags: jquery

I am using `jQuery` data table, if there is no data, now its showing "No data available in table", when data is present I am trying to hide the `#contractDataTable_wrapper`, I tried following code for that...

NametypeLast ModifiedDate CreatedStatus
                                
                                    
                                        delete
                                    
                                
                        
                              
                        No data available in table

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     if ($(".contractsTable .table-responsive").find(".dataTables_empty")) {
            $('.dataTables_empty').parents("#contractDataTable_wrapper").hide();
            $(".contractsEmptyData ").css("display", "block");
        }
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide table row if all tds are empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346271/hide-table-row-if-all-tds-are-empty)

Comment: Post some `html` code too please..

Comment: If `.contractsEmptyData` is a cell, you must to set `display: table-cell` and not `display: block`, to avoid corrupted layout.

Comment: i need to hide table wropper

Answer (score 1):

Just check the `table tbody tr td` text

```
 var empty = $(".yourTable tbody tr:eq(0) td").html();
 if(empty == "No data available in table")
 {
    $("#contractDataTable_wrapper").hide();
 }
```

Comment: have you changed .yourTable to your desired table class ?
or at least give me a fiddle. 
This code works for me!

Comment: not working , bcz first row is same data is ther if data not there then it display msg " no data available in table"

Comment: your fiddle is empty!

Comment: in jsfiddle it is working but when put same code in my live project "alert coming is undefind" ?

Comment: Maybe with the datatable initialization

Comment: before loading the datatable function is excuted

Comment: when data table load, same time this function need call, but how ?

Comment: Is you table is initialized by datatable ?

Comment: If yes then at the end of your script add this code.

Comment: Or in your browser hit F12 and check for errors in your console if you cant find a bug then you have to show me your script plus pre initialized html. I know there is bug in your code. Mine code works like a charm with me as well as in jsfiddle I give you.

Comment: data is coming from api through jquery datatable

Comment: I dnt know whats the issue in your code. It would be nice if you share you jquery script.